# Retrieve intervals from array based on multiple ranges

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, intervals

Let's say I have a Numpy array called a:

```
a = np.array([2,3,8,11,30,39,44,49,55,61])
```

I would like to retrieve multiple intervals based on two other arrays:

```
l = np.array([2,5,42])
r = np.array([10,40,70])
```

Doing something equivalent to this:

```
a[(a > l) & (a < r)]
```

With this as the desired output:

```
Out[1]: [[3 8],[ 8 11 30 39],[44 49 55 61]]
```

Of course I could do a simple `for` loop iterating over `l` and `r`, but the real life dataset is huge, so I would like to prevent looping as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid looping given the ragged nature of output. But we should try to reduce compute when iterating. So, here's one way to simply slice into the input array while iterating, as we will most of the compute part with getting the start,stop indices per group with `searchsorted` -

```
lidx = np.searchsorted(a,l,'right')
ridx = np.searchsorted(a,r,'left')
out = [a[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(lidx,ridx)]
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I was indeed afraid I couldn't avoid looping in this instance. I'll use both options and see what works best for the task.

Comment: I timed it. Your code was slightly faster. The thing is, this question was just a part of a much larger script that needs to be as efficient as possible. Hence I am trying to avoid looping.

Comment: @pr94 Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, broadcasting to obtain the indexing arrays, and using `np.split` to split the array:

```
# generates a (3,len(a)) where the windows are found in each column
w = (a[:,None] > l) & (a[:,None] < r)
# indices where in the (3,len(a)) array condition is satisfied
ix, _ = np.where(w)
# splits according to the sum along the columns
np.split(a[ix], np.cumsum(w.sum(0)))[:-1]
# [array([3, 8]), array([ 8, 11, 30, 39]), array([44, 49, 55, 61])]
```

Comment: That `np.split` uses `array_split` and that uses looping - https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.4/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L737-L790.

Comment: Right, I was aware it wasn't particularly fast, but didn't know about that thx @divakar